# Trying to get user input to print in a P element

Tags: javascript, html, user-input

I would like to be able to take user input of a first and last name and upon clicking a submit button update a P element with that first and last name. almost like "Hello firstname lastname!"

The code I've provided is what my click function currently looks like.

```js
function newName(){
var Name = input.value;


if (Name==""){
document.getElementById("hello").innerHTML="Hello" + Name;
}
};
```

Comment: What is the issue?

Comment: Invert your if condition. You have `if (Name=="")` and you need `if(Name!="")`

Comment: Also, if you're setting text, don't use `innerHTMl`, use `textContent`. And since we're in modern JS, it's a good idea to stop using `+` and instead use templating strings, so: ```element.textContent = `Hello ${name}!`;```

Comment: To piggy-back on @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans, you don't want to use innerHTML because it can allow someone to inject HTML into your website.

Comment: https://gomakethings.com/preventing-cross-site-scripting-attacks-when-using-innerhtml-in-vanilla-javascript/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `trim()` to remove blank spaces and then check the condition.

```js
var firstName = document.querySelector('#firstName');
var lastName = document.querySelector('#lastName');

function updateName() {
  if (firstName.value.trim() && lastName.value.trim()) {
    document.getElementById("hello").textContent = `Hello ${firstName.value} ${lastName.value}`;
  }
};
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Firstname" id="firstName" />
<input type="text" placeholder="Firstname" id="lastName" />

<button onclick="updateName()">Click</button>
<p id="hello">
</p>
```

Comment: On a "real world" note, just ask for "name", not "first name" and "last name". At best ask for "full name" and "what should we call you in emails that we might send you" or something. The planet has a _lot_ of different naming schemes, and some countries have subgroups that literally only have a single name. Even in Europe and North America, people can legally have only a single name, and too many websites have already been erroneously made to reject those entirely valid names.

Answer (score 0):

function getName(){
  let name = input.value;

if (name != ""){
       document.getElementById("name").textContent = `Hi ${name}`;
   }
}

Answer (score -1):

This would be the most concise way to do it. Since this is simple test function.

```
function newName(){
if(input.value !== undefined || ""){
document.getElementById("hello").innerHTML= 'Hello '+ input.value }
};
```

Answer (score -1):

Your code should look like below. JS Fiddle here for quick reference: https://jsfiddle.net/sagarag05/5nteLzm6/3/

```
function newName(){
  let fullName = input.value; 

   if (fullName != ""){
       document.getElementById("fullName2").textContent = `Hello ${name}`;
   }
}
```